# Найти совпадения по командам в начале текста

Tags: python, python-3.x

У нас есть много разных команд:

```
commands = [{
        'icon': '',
        'command': 'поцеловать',
        'text': 'поцеловал(а)'
    },
    {
        'icon': '',
        'command': 'обнять',
        'text': 'обнял(а)'
    },
    {
        'icon': '',
        'command': 'засосать',
        'text': 'засосал(а)'
    },
    {
        'icon': '',
        'command': 'ударить',
        'text': 'ударила(а)'
    },
    {
        'icon': '',
        'command': 'поцеловать тебя',
        'text': 'жёстко поцеловала'
    },
    {
        'icon': '',
        'command': 'откос',
        'text': 'откосил(а) у' 
    },
    {
        'icon': '',
        'command': 'крем',
        'text': 'откремил(а) у'
    }]
```

И возможность вызова с разными аргументами в конце

```
cmd_string = "иди сюда ты 1"
cmd_string = "иди сюда ты https://site.ru/userid1"
```

и тд.

Как можно проверить есть ли в начале текста совпадение с определённой командой и если есть разделять их с конечным аргументом, на выходе требуется получить:

```
({"command": "иди сюда ты"}, "1")
```

и тд..

Но при этом конечного аргумента может и не быть в таком случае возвращать просто команду

```
({"command": "иди сюда ты"})
```

Моя попытка была довольно крива и не логична:

```
module = list(filter(lambda modules: modules['command'].startswith(cmd_string), commands))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из того, что вижу. У Вас ошибка в обработке команды и строки с не. Вы проверяете `команду` на вхождение в нее строки `запроса`. Нужно наоборот. Такой вариант всегда даст `False`.

```
cmd_strings = ["поцеловать тебя https://site.ru/userid1", "обнять https://site.ru/userid1", 'обнять', 'обнять https://site.ru/userid1 https://site.ru/userid1',]

commands_list = sorted([c['command'] for c in commands], reverse=True)
cmd_commands = [next(filter(lambda c: c in cmd, commands_list)) for cmd in cmd_strings]
module = [[{'command': c}, cmd.partition(c)[-1].strip()] for c, cmd in zip(cmd_commands, cmd_strings)]

print(*module, sep='\n')
```

Принт:

```
[{'command': 'поцеловать тебя'}, 'https://site.ru/userid1']
[{'command': 'обнять'}, 'https://site.ru/userid1']
[{'command': 'обнять'}, '']
[{'command': 'обнять'}, 'https://site.ru/userid1 https://site.ru/userid1']
```

Структура списка команд по мне будет лучше работать, если все сделать в виде словаря, а на ключи словаря дальше функцию обработки уже вешать. Но что есть.

Comment: Решение хорошое, но я извиняюсь не уточнил мой косяк, команда так же может быть без пробелов по типу `приветкакдела 1` и тд. Тогда ваше решение не тригерится(

Comment: Была идея через `replace()`, но думаю, что код будет читабельнее и компактнее при предварительной замене неразбитой пробелами команды на правильную, а потом уже обработка.

Comment: Если в команде есть структура а - ля

    `{'icon': '','command': 'поцеловать тебя',text': ''}`
То он выдает довольно странную конструкцию причем 2
`[[{'command': 'поцеловать'}, 'тебя'], [{'command': 'поцеловать тебя'}, '']]`

Comment: Можете полную конструкцию добавить в свой первый пост? Чтобы понимать что и с чем соотносится

Comment: обновил коммандную структуру в посту

Comment: Все, понял. У вас накладывается две команды `поцеловать` и `поцеловать тебя`. В результате обе обрабатываются. Тут сортировку команд по длине стоит делать с поиском первого совпадения.

Comment: @Michael обновил

Comment: переделал под одну команду, но в конце выводит то же что и я скидывал, вот фулл код: https://codeshare.io/VZZRvO